# Angular 2 Array Subject .next() not invoking another component's observer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, firebase, rxjs

I'm using firebase as my backend.

Inside of a data.service.ts, I create a Subject array which will be filled by the firebase observer on app init:

```
private orders = new Subject<any>();
orders$ = this.orders.asObservable();

firebase.database().ref(this.fbDataPath).on('child_added', (childSnapshot) => {
  this.orders.next(
    {
      key: childSnapshot.key,
      name: childSnapshot.val().name,
      items: childSnapshot.val().items
    }
  )
})
```

I then provide a separate directory component with DataService and subscribe to its orders observable:

```
DataService.orders$.subscribe(
  order => {
    console.log('subscribe hit')
  })
```

I can't seem to get the listener component to trigger on a next. I made this work for a boolean isLoggedIn, and I must be missing something in this scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you're using `this` in a closure. Remove the `this` from `this.orders.next()`

Comment: That's not the problem since array functions capture `this` correctly

Comment: whoops, I wasn't marking as answered for the self... that didn't seem to work. However when I removed it from the firebase closure the subscribe was at least coming through...so I may have to roll my own firebase watcher unless there's something else?